# How did Evernote implement their rich text editor on iOS?

Tags: ios, evernote

Evernote recently released an [update](http://blog.evernote.com/2011/08/22/the-big-evernote-for-ios-update/) to their iOS client, including the first iOS rich text editor I've ever used. How does it work under the hood? WebView? CoreText?

Comment: Why ask us? Why not ask them?

Comment: Poorly.

They had access to iOS 5 beta for months now, and they couldn't get it to run at all on it. It's gonna be fun once iOS 5 goes public in the next few weeks and tis super cool new update breaks.

Comment: I used the new Evernote on my iPad to take conference notes last week and it couldn't keep up with my typing once I wrote more than a page of notes, even without formatting. I don't think there's some "super library" behind the scenes and wouldn't be particularly interested in using it myself.

Comment: so, finally, have you found the solution for ios rich text editor?