# How did Evernote implement their rich text editor on Android?

Tags: android, evernote, richtext, rich-text-editor

As asked here: [How did Evernote implement their rich text editor on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275640/how-did-evernote-implement-their-rich-text-editor-on-ios)

I've been struggling to find a third-party library for rich text editing on Android. I've just installed Evernote's Android client and they have a pretty nice solution. Anyone in the know as to how they did it?

**edit**

For anyone looking, the Wordpress app contains a WYSIWYG-ish editor that's open-source:

https://android.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/org/wordpress/android/EditContent.java

Comment: Going out on a limb here, but I am going to guess that they used a WebView with HTML.  So, each of the items in the menu opened on closed html tags.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, due to the extreme bugginess in Android's ContentEditable implementation (I've tried it, it's not pretty).

Comment: Hi did u succeed in implementing richtexteditor.If so which one u used webview/edittext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some links that should help you get started:

http://code.google.com/p/android-richtexteditor/

[Rich Text Box in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952117/rich-text-box-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that first implementation. Interesting that the latest commit deletes all their source code... do they understand version control?